# Can't Connect to VisualStudio.com: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just started receiving this error in Visual Studio 2012 while trying to check in my project to VisualStudio.com .  I don't know what is causing it, I have tried rebooting the computer but it has not solved the problem.  Has anyone ever seen this before?

I am using the Team Foundation Service Preview.

`C:\Users\rjs3261\Documents\Visual Studio 11\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2.csproj: The server encountered an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Team Foundation servers are down, you can check the status here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

And here is my source:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfservice/archive/2013/02/22/service-interruption-2-22-2013-update.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the same error. Tried to check-in for the past couple of hours and every attempt results in this error.

There is a forum response on tfs.visualstudio.com. Looks like there is an Azure storage problem that is causing the issue.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/00965fe0-462e-4b73-8894-b263bbd25642

I also found the hosted TFS status dashboard: https://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/current-service-status